# How do I add a button to my list when I'm forced to use simple_list_item_1?

Tags: android, listview, layout

I have a list, and I want 'Next' and 'Previous' buttons at the bottom of the list. I've tried to make the ListAdapter for the list something other than simple_list_item_1, but Android won't let me. I keep getting '... can't be resolved'.

Now, simple_list_item_1 is some kind of magical unicorn that is impossible to find, so I can't change it.

How can I put my buttons on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary for you to use simple_list_item_1. Can you elaborate the "cant be resolved error". Also post your layout file and the code using those layout components.

Comment: I don't think this is an answer to the question.

Comment: could you elaborate on why its not an answer to this question?